# Find the $L^2$ norm of $\theta_\chi(z)^2$ in $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma_0(4)$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, modular-forms

I'd like to learn about $L^2$ norms on Hyperbolic space.  My Automorphic forms textbook says this function is a "cusp form" so it's in $L^2(\mathbb{H}/\Gamma_0(4))$:

$$ \theta_\chi(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \chi(n) \, e^{-\pi n^2 \, z} $$

This is a cusp form, since $\chi(0) = 0$ for any Dirichlet character $\chi$.  Can we do the integral over the fundamental region?

$$ L^2(\theta_\chi) =  \int_{\mathbb{H}/\Gamma_0(4)} |\theta_\chi(z)|^2 \, \frac{dx^2 + dy^2 }{y^2} $$

Have I written the norm correctly?  It's very likely that in some cases, my question is not well-posed and that can be discussed in the comments or I'll up-vote an answer.

---

It seems the original version of my question is problematic. At least 
$\theta_\chi(z)^2$ is a weight 1 (?) cusp form over $\Gamma_0(4)$ and the question $L^2$ makes sense.

$$ \theta_\chi(z)^2 = \sum_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \chi(n) \, e^{-2\pi i (m^2+n^2 )\, z} $$

I may have to name a specific [Dirichlet character](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character). Perhaps the mod 4 character with $\chi(3)=-1$? And then we are integrating the absolute value squared over hyperbolic space:

$$| \theta_\chi(z)|^4 = \sum_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^4} \chi(n) \, e^{-2\pi i (a^2+b^2) -(c^2+d^2) )\, z} $$

We obtain a theta series associated to a quadratic form $q(z)=(a^2+b^2) -(c^2+d^2) $. The area form should be corrected as well

$$ L^2(\theta_\chi^2) =  \int_{\mathbb{H}/\Gamma_0(4)} |\theta_\chi(z)|^4 \, \frac{dx \, dy}{y^2} $$

Is this question well stated?

Comment: What text are you using? Generically, in order for it to be a cusp form it is also necessary to check the behavior at all the cusps, instead of just $\infty$. Here, that means also at $0$ and at $1/2$. Secondly, you have not written the measure correctly. The Haar measure here is $dx dy / y^2$, no addition.

Comment: What is $\chi$? If this is the standard theta function (section 10.5 of Iwaniec "Topics..."), then $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character modulo $1$, so $\chi(0) = 1$. Also your definition of $\theta_{\chi}(z)$ does not include $z$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: Also theta functions are half-integral weight modular forms; they're certainly not the most natural automorphic objects to study compared to, say, Eisenstein series of integral weight.

Comment: The question still doesn't make sense. First off, $\theta_{\chi}(z)^2$ is equal to $\sum_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \chi(mn) e^{2\pi i (m^2 + n^2)z}$. Secondly, the correct definition of the theta function is $\theta_{\chi}(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} n^{\kappa} \chi(n) e^{2\pi i n^2 z}$, where $\kappa \in \{0,1\}$ is such that $\chi(-1) = (-1)^{\kappa}$. If $\chi$ is a primitive Dirichlet character modulo $q$, then this is a modular form of weight $\kappa + 1/2$ and level $4q^2$. So you should not be taking $\chi$ to be the quadratic character modulo $4$ for this to be level $4$!

Comment: @cactus314 See [Garrett](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_c/analytic_continuations.pdf) p.6, you need to apply the Poisson summation formula with $f(t) = t e^{-\pi t^2 x}$ when $\chi(-1 )= -1$ is an odd character

Comment: $dxdy=d\Re(z) d\Im(z)$ is the surface measure. Since $\gamma(z)$ is conformal  $d\Re(\gamma(z)) d\Im(\gamma(z)) = |\gamma'(z)|^2 dxdy$.  Also $\gamma'(z) = \frac{1}{(cz+d)^2}$ and $\Im(\gamma(z))= \frac{\Im(z)}{|cz+d|^2}$ thus $\frac{dxdy}{y^2}$ is $\gamma\in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ invariant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard way to calculate norms of these types of objects is to unfold against an Eisenstein series. Let
\[E(z,s) = \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_{\infty} \backslash \Gamma_0(4q^2)} \Im(\gamma z)^s\]
denote the usual Eisenstein series associated to the cusp at infinity of $\Gamma_0(4q^2) \backslash \mathbb{H}$. This has a pole at $s = 1$ with residue $1/\mathrm{vol}(\Gamma_0(4q^2) \backslash \mathbb{H})$ *independently of $z$*.

Suppose that $\chi$ is a primitive Dirichlet character modulo $q$ satisfying $\chi(-1) = (-1)^{\kappa}$. Define
\[\theta_{\chi}(z) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} n^{\kappa} \chi(n) e(n^2 z),\]
where $e(z) = e^{2\pi i z}$. This satisfies
\[\theta_{\chi}(\gamma z) = \chi(d) \overline{\varepsilon}_d \left(\frac{c}{d}\right) (cz + d)^{\kappa + 1/2} \theta_{\chi}(z)\]
for all $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma_0(4q^2)$. That is, this is a half-integral weight modular form. If $q > 1$, this vanishes at the cusp at infinity. In any case, we note that for $\Re(s) > 1$, the integrand of
\[\int_{\Gamma_0(4q^2) \backslash \mathbb{H}} |\theta_{\chi}(z)|^2 E(z,s) \Im(z)^{\kappa + \frac{1}{2}} \, \frac{dx \, dy}{y^2}\]
is equal to
\[\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_{\infty} \backslash \Gamma_0(4q^2)} |\theta_{\chi}(\gamma z)|^2 \Im(\gamma z)^{s + \kappa + \frac{1}{2}}\]
via the automorphy of $\theta_{\chi}(z)$. By unfolding the integral, we obtain
\[\int_{\Gamma_{\infty} \backslash \mathbb{H}} |\theta_{\chi}(z)|^2 \Im(z)^{s + \kappa + \frac{1}{2}} \, \frac{dx \, dy}{y^2} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} |\theta_{\chi}(z)|^2 y^{s + \kappa - \frac{1}{2}} \, dx \, \frac{dy}{y}.\]
We replace $\theta_{\chi}(z)$ with its Fourier expansion and interchange the order of integration and summation, yielding
\[\sum_{n_1 = -\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{n_2 = -\infty}^{\infty} (n_1 n_2)^{\kappa} \chi(n_1) \overline{\chi}(n_2) \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2\pi(n_1^2 + n_2^2) y} y^{s + \kappa - \frac{1}{2}} \, \frac{dy}{y} \int_{0}^{1} e((n_1^2 - n_2^2) x) \, dx.\]
Only the diagonal terms $n_1 = \pm n_2$ survive the integration over $x$, yielding
\[4 \sum_{\substack{n = 1 \\ (n,q) = 1}}^{\infty} n^{2\kappa} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-4\pi n^2 y} y^{s + \kappa - \frac{1}{2}} \, \frac{dy}{y}.\]
We make the change of variables $y \mapsto y/(4\pi n^2)$, so that the integral becomes
\[(4\pi n^2)^{-s - \kappa + \frac{1}{2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y} y^{s + \kappa - \frac{1}{2}} \, \frac{dy}{y}.\]
This integral is simply $\Gamma(s + \kappa - 1/2)$. So the original integral is equal to
\[4 (4\pi)^{-s - \kappa + \frac{1}{2}} \Gamma\left(s + \kappa - \frac{1}{2}\right) \sum_{\substack{n = 1 \\ (n,q) = 1}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2s - 1}}.\]
This Dirichlet series is equal to $\zeta(2s - 1) \prod_{p \mid q} (1 - p^{-(2s - 1)})$.

Now we take the residue at $s = 1$. The left-hand side is equal to
\[\frac{1}{\mathrm{vol}\left(\Gamma_0(4q^2) \backslash \mathbb{H}\right)} \int_{\Gamma_0(4q^2) \backslash \mathbb{H}} |\theta_{\chi}(z)|^2 \Im(z)^{\kappa + \frac{1}{2}} \, \frac{dx \, dy}{y^2}.\]
The right-hand side is equal to
\[2 (4\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2} - \kappa} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} + \kappa\right) \prod_{p \mid q} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).\]

Comment: After that, a question would be : can we hope a way to interpret it in the opposite direction, using the structure of $\Gamma_0(4k!^2),\chi$ to estimate $\prod_{p | k!} (1-1/p)$ ? In particular the PNT and the zero-free regions of $\zeta(s)$ should have a clear meaning in term of the behavior and the value at the cusps of $\theta_{\chi}$ with $\chi$ a primitive character modulo $k!$ as $k \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The standard, but non-obvious, way to compute an $L^2$ norm of a modular form $f$ is as the residue at $s=1$ of the Rankin-Selberg $L$-function (or Dirichlet series) obtained as an integral $\int_{\Gamma\\\mathfrak H} E_s\cdot |f|^2$. This is because the residue at $s=1$ of that Eisenstein series is a constant (basically the multiplicative inverse of the natural volume of $\Gamma\backslash\mathfrak H$). For half-integral weight theta series, after the corrections indicated by @Peter Humphries are made, you can identify this Rankin-Selberg thing as an already-familiar Dirichlet series, whose reside at $1$ is known in other terms.

EDIT: "The" weight-zero Eisenstein series attached to the cusp $i\infty$ for $\Gamma_0(N)$ is $\sum_{c,d} y^2/|cz+d|^{2s}$ where $c,d$ are summed over relatively prime integers congruent to $0,1$ mod $N$, and multiplicatively modulo $\pm 1$ for $N=2$.

Comment: +1 Can you write out the $\Gamma_0(4)$ Eisenstein series? It's sum over $(c,d)=1$. Any other conditions?

Comment: @cactus314, you have asked this question before, and I have answered it before; you need $c \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries, do you understand the/an underlying cause for the repetition?

Comment: @paulgarrett I think you meant $\displaystyle E_{s,\Gamma_0(N)}(z) = \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_0(N)/T} \Im(\gamma(z))^s=\sum_{(c,d)=1, c \equiv 0 \bmod N} \frac{y^s}{|cz+d|^{2s}}$ where $T(z)=z+1$ and $\displaystyle E_{s,\Gamma_1(N)}(z) = \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_1(N)/T} \Im(\gamma(z))^s =\sum_{(c,d)=1, c \equiv 0 \bmod N, d \equiv 1 \bmod N} \frac{y^s}{|cz+d|^{2s}}$. There is also $\displaystyle E_{s,\Gamma_0(N),\chi}(z) = \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_0(N)/T} \chi(\gamma)\Im(\gamma(z))^s =\sum_{(c,d)=1, c \equiv 0 \bmod N}\chi(d) \frac{y^s}{|cz+d|^{2s}}$ for any Dirichlet character $\chi$ modulo $N$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand $\theta_\chi$ in detail, how to estimate an upper bound for $\langle \theta_\chi E_{s,\Gamma_0(N)},\theta_\chi \rangle$ in particular the value of $\theta_\chi$ at the cusps $\pm 1/m, m| N$ for many primitive (possibly quadratic and even) characters. Any idea where to search ? @PeterHumphries

Comment: @reuns, remind me on Monday and I will have a think.

Comment: @reuns, oop, yes, you're right, of course. Thanks!